# Angular-Google-Chart - using the same controller for showing two graphs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to change the default text showed in the tooltip of chart.

I tried including tooltip column and add the row for the tooltip but it is not showing the text i have assigned. Any inputs.

How to show the user defined data on the tooltip on mouseover?

Comment: you have two questions and you should keep it to one question at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, the `view` definition doesn't include the index for the tooltip column,
need to add (5)...

```
$chart.view = {
  columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  // <-- add 5 here
};
```

next, the tooltip column doesn't need a property for `label`,
but it does need one for `role`
the column definition should be...

```
{id:"tooltip", role:"tooltip", type:"string"}
```

also, just a note, the variable declaration for `status` is missing...

```
var laptop;
var desktop;
var shipping;
var server;
var status;  // <--add declaration
var temp=0;
```